# UPDATE database value with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to update a database value each time complete() occurs. The following code is located in a file called 'user.php' and $u is globally defined elsewhere in the file. The value pT simply doesn't update when complete() is ran. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['pT'])){
        $pT = $_POST['pT'];

        $sql = "UPDATE progress SET progressbar='$pT' WHERE username='$u'";
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        exit();
    }
?>

var pT = 0;

function complete(){

    pT = pT + 25;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'user.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'pT': pT},
        success: function() {}
    });

}
```

Comment: you dont need quotes round the pT `data: {pT: pT}`

Comment: Have you checked developers console?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Where does `$u` derived from, is this causing the issue? What debugging have you done? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: How do you call `complete()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. split the files

   ```
   user.php
   _______
   <?php
   if (isset($_POST['pT'])){
       $pT = $_POST['pT'];

       $sql = "UPDATE progress SET progressbar='$pT' WHERE username='$u'";
       $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

       exit();
   }
   ?>
   ```

---

2. then make sure your javascript/jquery ajax isn't malformed

   ```
   somewherelse.html
   ____________
   var pT = 0;

   function complete(){

     pT = pT + 25;

     $.ajax({
       url: 'user.php',
       type: 'POST',
       data: 'pT='+ pT,
       success: function() {
           alert('done');
       }
     });

   }
   ```

Comment: jQuery will automatically format the post data when you provide an object. IMHO it's generally preferable to use an object instead of a string, so you don't forget to escape special characters when necessary.